# What is the best approach to check if an object exists in angular firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

We are creating a mobile application using Ionic framework (Ionic2). For backend, we are using Firebase database and authentication. Let say we have a data structure like this in our firebase database :-

```
user-list
_________
{

    email1 :
        {
            name:'1'
            phone:'01'
        }

    email2 :
        {
            name:'2'
            phone:'02'
        }

    email3 :
        {
            name:'3'
            phone:'03'
        }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

We want to get the parent object by searching firebase db with the phone number. No updates or insertion are going to take place. So, if search is performed with '03' phone number, we have get the object :

```
email3 :
    {
        name:'3'
        phone:'03'
    }
```

We have followed many approaches as of now, but nothing has worked so far. All the approaches seem to work when a new object is entered on the list. Any solution / direction will be very appreciated.

Note: We are using [angularfire2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularfire2)  to incorporate firebase in our Ionic2 project